# Angular2 and BootStrap-Toggle

Tags: angular

I'm trying to use [Bootstrap-Toggle](http://www.bootstraptoggle.com/) in a Angular2 project and I can't get it working.

I did some debugging and I it see properly displaying but after all the initialization occurs it goes back to a normal checkbox.

It appears the problem has to due with Bootstrap-Toggle adding elements directly to the DOM.

How can I get Bootstrap-Toggle working in Angular2?

[image: Bootstrap-Toggle checkbox]

Comment: Hey there, It'd be better if you can add the code that you're writing to make this work. So that we can help. How are you doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialize it with java script like that 
in ngOninit() in your component relative to that template

```
ngOninit(){
  $("#toggleId").bootstrapToggle();
}
```